# How to name a CSV file with yesterday's date?

Tags: csv, sql-server-2005, ssis

I need a SQL job to run every day.

This CSV file needs to be named with yesterday’s date.  So, if this job was to run today, it would generate a file called 20160820_invoices.csv.

I use following code but it does not work.

```
"C:\\Invoices_" + (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GetDate()) ,2) + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEADD("dd", -1, GetDate()),2) + ".csv"`
```

Is there any other way I can correct it to get it to work?

Comment: In what way does it not work? It looks like SSIS expression so I will add that tag for you while you edit your question and explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: For starters your example has the date leading the file name but your code has it trailing. Is that why it doesn't work?

Comment: first of all Thank you Nick. I 'm able to create .csv file in SQL Server with yesterday's date. 2, Can I copy this file in network folder too? using SSIS? if yes then please guide me how? Thanks

Comment: Is that what you mean by 'doesn't work'? If you want to copy a file use a file system task. <rant>I learnt IT by laboriously trawling through books and help files. Nowadays its a five second google search and people can't even do that</rant>

Answer (score 1):

```
"C:\\Invoices_" + CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(d, -1, current_timestamp), 112) + ".csv"
```